# What is wrong?! preg_match only numbers

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match

Sorry for my bad English. Here is my question:

I have a $ str with the following content:  "1122 Here is my string [ABC: 123456]"

I take:

```
preg_match("/\d+/",$string,$result);
echo $result[0];
```

That's ok , the result is correct. 1122

But I just want the number of this here: [ABC: 123456]
Not from this:  "123 Here is my string...."

I take:

```
preg_match("/\[\d+\]/",$string,$result);
echo $result[0];
```

But the result is...
"Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in Line.... "

What ist wrong?

**EDIT:**
OK , maybe there is an easier way. The numbers that I need always begin with "G015". Behind then followed by other numbers 1,14,80,123, and so on...

And this is always in brackets. So as "A text, whatever [G015123]".

Maybe someone has an idea , how do I get this number in order to continue working ?

Answer (score 1):

you forget your capturing parentheses

```
    preg_match("/(\d+)/",$string,$result);
    echo $result[0];
```

also you can use **preg_match_all()** to capture all your digit

```
$string = "1122 Here is my string [ABC: 123456]";
preg_match_all("/(\d+)/",$string,$result);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it to match one or more inside the set. `/[\d+]/` should be `/([\d]+)/` for that code.

If you want to match all #'s in your string not just the first you need to use preg_match_all()